# How to handle the ownership transfer of a unique pointer's stored raw pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

How to handle a scenario where I have a unique pointer with custom deleter, but a 3rd party library's function expects a raw pointer and I pass the stored pointer in the unique_ptr with .get(), but this function takes ownership of the raw pointer.

Example:

Initialize the unique pointers with custom deleter:

```
std::unique_ptr<BIGNUM, decltype(&BN_free)> r(BN_bin2bn(signature.data(), bnLen, nullptr), &BN_free);
std::unique_ptr<BIGNUM, decltype(&BN_free)> s(BN_bin2bn(signature.data() + bnLen, bnLen, nullptr), &BN_free);
```

Pass them to the ECDSA_SIG function, which takes the ownership of the r and s unique pointers:

```
ECDSA_SIG_set0(ecDsaSignature.get(), r.get(), s.get()))
```

At the end of the scope the custom deleter is called, but it crashes because the r and s were moved. I was thinking about using raw pointers, but what happens if the ECDSA_SIG_set0 function call is unsuccessful, do I have to manually free the r and s variables? Is this the correct way, or is there a more elegant way to handle this scenario?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the `.release()` function do the trick? That returns the embedded raw pointer and 'unowns' the object but, from what I can tell from [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), your deleter will sill be called when the smart pointer goes out of scope. I think.

Comment: Not sure what you're reading that suggests that your deleter will still be called if you've released a pointer. "The object is disposed of...when the _managing_ `unique_ptr` object is destroyed". It's no longer the managing `unique_ptr` after it's released the raw pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I pass the stored pointer in the unique_ptr with .get(), but this function takes ownership of the raw pointer.

If the function takes ownership, then you should release the ownership from the unique pointer. Otherwise the ownership won't be unique and you will get undefined behaviour due to multiple calls to the deleter. This is what the `release` member function is for.

> but what happens if the ECDSA_SIG_set0 function call is unsuccessful, do I have to manually free the r and s variables?

If the function takes ownership of the pointer, then it is responsible for deleting it (until it transfers the ownership somewhere else). If the function sometimes leaks the pointer, then it is a badly designed API.

What the function does should be specified in its documentation. It would be much better to use `std::unique_ptr` in the API if it takes ownership.

Comment: `ECDSA_SIG_set0` does indeed claim ownership of the passed pointers: [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/ECDSA_SIG_set0.html): *Non-NULL r and s values can be set on the sig by calling ECDSA_SIG_set0(). Calling this function transfers the memory management of the values to the ECDSA_SIG object, and therefore the values that have been passed in should not be freed by the caller.* - Also it can never fail (unless you pass nullptrs): [source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/9dddcd90a1350fa63486cbf3226c3eee79f9aff5/crypto/ec/ec_asn1.c#L1296-L1305)

Comment: So the only special case that would need to be handled would be if one of the pointers passed to `ECDSA_SIG_set0` was nullptr - in that case `ECDSA_SIG_set0` would fail and the caller is on the hook for freeing the other parameter.

Comment: so checking the r and s for nullptr, and if its not null, then pass them with .release() instead of .get()?

Comment: @Csuszmusz I'd recommend a pattern like this if you don't know if one of the pointers might potentially be null: `if(ECDSA_SIG_set0(ecDsaSignature.get(), r.get(), s.get()))) { /* function has taken over ownership */ r.release(); s.release(); }` - if you know that both will always be non-null you can call it with release directly: `ECDSA_SIG_set0(ecDsaSignature.get(), r.release(), s.release());`